# How to catch a github exception

Tags: python

Im trying to get commits from Github. But i run into a 409 error, i want to retry after it fails.
Im thinking the problem is with not catching the error correctly from GithubExceptions.

```
df_commits = pd.DataFrame(columns=['repo', 'commits', 'user' , 'created_at'])
    for repo in org.get_repos():
commits = repo.get_commits(since=datetime(2022, 9, 1))
for commits in commits:
    try:
        df_commits = df_commits.append({'repo': repo.name, 'commits': commits, 'user' : 
   commits.author, 'created_at' : commits.commit.author.date}, ignore_index=True)
    except:
        GithubException == 409
        print(GithubException)
        continue
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Q4V\Documents\VanOordProjects\Github\commits.py", line 16, in <module>
    for commits in commits:
  File "C:\Users\Q4V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\github\PaginatedList.py", line 56, in __iter__
    newElements = self._grow()
  File "C:\Users\Q4V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\github\PaginatedList.py", line 67, in _grow
    newElements = self._fetchNextPage()
  File "C:\Users\Q4V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\github\PaginatedList.py", line 199, in _fetchNextPage
    headers, data = self.__requester.requestJsonAndCheck(
  File "C:\Users\Q4V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\github\Requester.py", line 
353, in requestJsonAndCheck
    return self.__check(
  File "C:\Users\Q4V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\github\Requester.py", line 
378, in __check
    raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
github.GithubException.GithubException: 409 {"message": "Git Repository is empty.", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/commits/commits#list-commits"}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: When you get an error that says "Git Repository is empty", do you expect to retry and for the repo to no longer be empty?

Comment: `except github.GithubException.GithubException as exc: print(exc); continue`.

Comment: @JacobIRR, no start with the next Git Repository.

Comment: "How to catch a github exception" is a better title than "How do I retry a[n] python loop".

Comment: @9769953 good point.
Changed my code but still it is breaking at the 409. You got any other pointers?

Comment: What do you think `GithubException == 409` does?

Comment: `for commits in commits` maybe `for commit in commits`. Mind the variable names. Please be sure you have posted the correct code. There are indentation errors and variable misspellings there.

Comment: @alec_djinn,
Catch the 409 error and then work on the continue.
But that doesn't work.
And with the commit in commits i will get attribute error.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I checked for the 403 error:

```
from github import GithubException
    result = []
    organization = g.get_organization("org_name")
    invites = organization.invitations()
    try:
        #get invites from result
        for invite in invites:
            print(result.append(invite))
    except GithubException as e:
        if e.status== 403:
            print("You need admin access")
```

Reference: [GithubException Class](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/GithubException.py)

Note: ***e.data*** gives the actual exception data.

**Update: There are specific exceptions to raise which are shown [here](https://github.com/unskript/Awesome-CloudOps-Automation/blob/master/Github/legos/github_get_pull_request/github_get_pull_request.py)**

This [open-source repository](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/GithubException.py) has many pre-build Github actions made using PyGithub that we can use directly for any automations. (Mentioning this as I found it to be really cool)

They are creating an open-source framework for writing Runbooks using Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of catching exceptions. I will make just two examples below. Please [read more](https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/) on how to properly use the try/except block. The problem with your code is that GithubException, as you typed it, is just a variable name, probably not even defined.

You can try:

```
for commit in commits:
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'got Exception {e}')
        continue
```

The block below will catch any exception and continue.

You can be more sophisticated and check the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to continue only if a particular error message is given.

```
import traceback


for commit in commits:
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        if 'Git Repository is empty' in tb:
            print(f'The repo is empty!')
            continue
        else:
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you.
It is not working but i get what is wrong.
The PyGithub package doesnt have attribute to handle 409 errors. So i need to find a way to handle that manually.

Comment: @Eindbaas The second snipped of code I wrote is exactly for that.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem keeps occurring with the second solution.
Do you have any direction to find a solution?

Comment: @Eindbaas In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it is, the code you provided is not reproducible. I need to be able to reproduce the error to fix it. There are several things going wrong with your code. Please post it all.